# Mongodb Is it possible to exclude the root document if only a nested document matches the result?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I have a set of documents which includes a nested set of revisions of that same document. I need to execute a search query that returns only the matched set, including the parent where matched. Below is a reduced example of the data.

```
{
"title_number": "46345734",
"status": "applied",
"updated": "02/04/2022",
"rev_num": 1,
"revs": [
  {
    "title_number": "46345734",
    "status": "unapplied",
    "updated": "02/06/2022",
    "rev_num": 2
  }]
},
{
"title_number": "46345802",
"status": "unapplied",
"updated": "02/05/2022",
"rev_num": 1,
"revs": [
  {
    "title_number": "46345802",
    "status": "applied",
    "updated": "02/05/2022",
    "rev_num": 2
  },
  {
    "title_number": "46345802",
    "status": "applied",
    "updated": "02/06/2022",
    "rev_num": 3
  }]
}
```

In one query, I want to look for all documents with a status of "unapplied", only returning the nested documents that match the status and keeping or removing the parent if it also matched.

Below is an example of how I expected the query to look initially, and the expected result when run against the provided example data.

```
titles.find({
  "$and": [{
    "$or": [
      {"status": "applied"},
      {"revs.status": "applied"}
    ]
  }]
})
```

Expected(Wanted) result

```
{
"title_number": "46345734",
"status": "applied",
"updated": "02/04/2022",
"rev_num": 1,
"revs": [],
},
{
  "title_number": "46345802",
  "status": "applied",
  "updated": "02/05/2022",
  "rev_num": 2
},
{
  "title_number": "46345802",
  "status": "applied",
  "updated": "02/06/2022",
  "rev_num": 3
}
```

In the first result, the parent status matched, but not the child, so only the parent was returned. In the second result, the parent didn't match, however, two of the nested documents did, so only they were returned.

After reading a ton of posts regarding aggregates, element matching, etc, I have been able to get bits and pieces, but it seems my case is either insanely obvious or rather unique.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `aggregate` and first [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) revs with applied `status` and then [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) applied docs to separate array and also the `revs` to another array and finally mix two array to one.

you can test it here [mongodb playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zCvWooIRgG5)

```
titles.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "revs": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$revs",
          as: "rev",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$rev.status",
              "applied"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      applied_doc: {
        $push: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$status",
                "applied"
              ]
            },
            {
              _id: "_id",
              title_number: "$title_number",
              status: "$status",
              updated: "$updated",
              rev_num: "$rev_num",
              revs: "$revs"
            },
            "$$REMOVE"
          ]
        }
      },
      applied_sub_doc: {
        $push: "$revs"
      }
    },
    
  },
  // flatten array in $applied_sub_doc prop
  {
    $set: {
      applied_sub_doc: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$applied_sub_doc",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ],
            
          },
          
        },
        
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $project: {
      mixedDocs: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$applied_doc",
          "$applied_sub_doc"
        ],
        
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$mixedDocs",
    
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$mixedDocs",
    
  },
  
])
```

Comment: Hello, Sina. Thank you for the reply. The playground result looks great and appears I have my homework cut out for me. I have a quick question regarding the "$cond" fields. If I wanted to expand that with another condition, would it be as simple as adding it to the list? For example, 
cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$rev.status",
              "applied"
            ],
$gte: ["$$rev.updated", "02/05/2022"],
$lte: ["$$rev.updated", "02/06/2022"]
          }
 Assuming of course I have properly modeled the timestamps.

Comment: yes you can but you have to use [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) or [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

Comment: Fantastic, thanks again! The testing with the full data set is working as expected in mongoplayground and I have accepted your answer. Once last bit, it you don't mind. I am unable to find anything on the "false" case of the conditional. In your example, you use "$$REMOVE". Do you know where I might find that in the mongodb documentation? I have looked at the /operator/aggregation/cond/ document, and it is not mentioned anywhere. I am attempting to convert the syntax to something pymongo friendly, and it trips on that part in particular.

Comment: you're welcome, you can find it [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#mongodb-variable-variable.REMOVE)